# How to Train Brain.js Neural Network in Bulk with Dynamic DataSet?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, dynamic, brain.js

I am having hard time figuring out how to train the brain.js neural network with dynamic dataset. The GitHub documentation says the following: **Each training pattern should have an input and an output, both of which can be either an array of numbers from 0 to 1 or a hash of numbers from 0 to 1**

```
net.train([{input: [0, 0], output: [0]},
           {input: [0, 1], output: [1]},
           {input: [1, 0], output: [1]},
           {input: [1, 1], output: [0]}]);

const output = net.run([1, 0]);  // [0.987]
```

The problem is that I don't know beforehand how many elements are in the input array of my training data so I don't know how many {input: [0, 0], output: [0]} elements I need to pass to net.train().

For example:
How do I train the neural network if I have the following arrays without hardcoding the number of {input: [0, 0], output: [0]} elements.

```
var input1_array = [.1, .2, .3, .4, .5]
var input2_array = [.6, .7, .8, .9, .95]
var output1_array = [.2, .6, .8, .85, .95]

// the following doesn't work 
net.train([input:[input1_array, input2_array], output:[output1_array]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope question is still valid.

First, I would start with blank array (i.e/ `input1_array=[];`), but you can't do it as in train  you need to have some value. For that reason you can put some initial data like 
`var input1_array = [0];` if your network will have two inputs then `var input1_array = [0,0];`

If you will use two or more previous values as inputs you will need

```
var trainingdata= [{input: [0, 0], output: [0]},
           {input: [0, 1], output: [1]},
] //(sorry for typos, but idea to have two entries)
```

Now you have some initial zeros to not have NULL going to you NN.
I was using prompt during testing and input did the following
     `trainingdata.push (input:[prompt("Enter next in value")],output:[prompt("Enter next out value")])`

Depending on what you do with the network, you may need retrain it each time a new value comes (like time series prediction with LSTM) or just collect data (NN type).

In your example replace prompt with whatever source of data like something from page (`getElementById`) or some server data JSON parsed value.

I found one trick. Make function to push to array is length

You can do something like:

```
if (trainingData.length < maxtrainingdata) {
  trainingData.push({input: [var1], output: [var2]});
}
else {
  trainingData.shift();
  trainingData.push({input: [var1], output: [
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty new to AI but my idea here is, to **make your dataset dynamic**.

1. So let's say you have an **AI that needs to learn how to answer to some questions** correctly.
2. In the beginning the AI will just answer them randomly with no idea of what it is doing.
3. You need to **make some testing environment** for it to learn.

With this **I mean create a piece of code in your AI that knows which answers are correct**, every time it gets it right push that result to the dynamic dataset.

**Let me give you another example.**

1. If you were training some AI to escape a room.
2. You would need to make a piece of code when it escapes that pushes those results to the dataset so it can learn the best possible ways to do it.

Did you understand?

Obviously this operation is very expensive.

If you want to train it constantly, you would need some real powerful processing power.

The best way you can work around this issues is by saving iterations.

Imagine that every 100 results you reboot and re-train, that would help. Or if you don't need to actively train it, you can just save push the data into a file that can be re-trained every time the AI reboots.

Your AI would become **smarter every time you reboot**